# How to include self signed Root CA into Windows setup USB/ISO?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to modify my Windows USB installer (Windows 10) to have a custom Root CA automatically in the Trusted Root Certification Authority store after Windows installation is complete, or even better if I can do so before installation by injecting it into the setup. Doing so manually can't be scalable for installations on many computers. As many people create custom ISOs, and sometimes even insert activator programs in it, which I am generally against, I assume injecting a custom root certificate shouldn't be impossible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This typically would be acomplished with [Sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11). What part of the process are you stuck on? How you customize a windows image is a well documented but non-trivial process that is not easily described in an answer unless its specific to a step in the process. How you create a Windows image could easily exceed 5,000 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [Sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11)
and install a custom certificate requires to
[Add a Custom Script to Windows Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd744268(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

You can find an example in the article
[Create Post Sysprep Script/Batch File on Image and Copy Certificate](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-DaaS/services/horizondaas.servicecenter900/GUID-BFE0B55A-60E0-4720-889A-48A37C23AF14.html):

> 1. Copy the SSL certificate file under C: drive. For this example, the “C:\desktone_ca_cert” file.
> 2. Create a file SetupComplete.cmd under "%WINDIR%\Setup\Scripts" folder. Create “Scripts” folder if it does not exist.
> 3. Add following commands in SetupComplete.cmd file. The thumbprint value is what you copied in Step 1.
>
>    **Note**: If you have root certificate and intermediate certificates in the certificate chain, then you need to add appropriate CertUtil
>    commands in batch file.
>
>    ```
>    CertUtil -importPFX -f -p "<password>" "C:\desktone_ca_cert.pfx"
>
>    reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware Blast\Config" /f /v "SslHash" /t REG_SZ /d "31 2a 32 50 1a 0b 34 b1 65 46 13 a8 0a 5e f7 43 6e a9 2c 3e"
>
>    del /F /Q "C:\desktone_ca_cert.pfx"
>
>    del /F /Q "%systemroot%\setup\scripts\SetupComplete.cmd"
>    ```
> 4. Save the SetupComplete.cmd file. You can test the SetupComplete.cmd file on test machine.

You will need to do some study in order to understand this process
and be able to write your own.

Comment: This involves mounting the .wim file using DISM right? I actually tried a similar method where I created the "Scripts" folder in the Setup folder of the mounted image. I mentioned to import certificate using certutil command and pointed to the certificate stored on USB itself. But for that method, I'm not sure how would I specify location when creating a .cmd script, as drive letters are dynamic in nature. Tried using X: but later found out that X is for a virtual partition named "boot" that is also created dynamically.

Comment: Sysprep is a heavy subject. My answer can only indicate a direction - too many details.

Comment: It worked! I observed that creating a .cmd file having the command 'certutil -addstore Root "%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\CA.crt" ' was no good as when I double clicked or right click > Run as Administrator the same, it simply wont work, but when I referenced it by opening CMD manually and ran SetupComplete.cmd, it worked. That made me modify the initial SetupComplete.cmd as 'powershell.exe -Command certutil -addstore Root "%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\CA.crt" ' which finally worked on running as admin.